# git diff merge-base with working tree (using ... notation)

Tags: git, git-diff

(Slightly different question than [Git diff branch against working tree not including merges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23975995/git-diff-branch-against-working-tree-not-including-merges))

Essentially I want `git diff origin/develop...working-tree`.

More technically what I want is `git diff $(git-merge-base origin/develop HEAD)` which will diff merge-base against working tree; Yet I want to keep the `...` shorthand at the same time.

The `origin/develop...` part calculates the correct merge-base (merge-base with HEAD), but it also is hardcoded to assume that the *comparison* is against HEAD as well. Is there a way to keep the `...` shorthand reference, but diff against working tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update Nov. 2020: Yes, that is now possible.

Running `git diff --merge-base <commit>` is equivalent to running `git diff $(git merge-base <commit> HEAD)` which should give you a diff between the merge-base and the current working tree.

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), "[`git diff A...B`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b6fb70c985a6fc113e971a6696f328abf8315dce/Documentation/git-diff.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup>" learned "[`git diff --merge-base A B`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b6fb70c985a6fc113e971a6696f328abf8315dce/Documentation/git-diff.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup>, which is a longer short-hand to say the same thing.

See [commit cce7d6e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cce7d6ecfc45f0d74a95c6ca6447d6e327791348), [commit 0f5a1d4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f5a1d449b9538c2765de9d6683abbb83a7fb4e2), [commit df7dbab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df7dbab881c1aa697f0826d8d00f73d43815acf5), [commit 177a830](https://github.com/git/git/commit/177a8302683da62a62b5b03e8192fcfa897db750), [commit 4c3fe82](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c3fe82ef17a6636c742b95cd292b83b02876e08) (20 Sep 2020), [commit 3d09c22](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d09c22869a7bd47f1683031937af0ed93b2fa3b) (14 Sep 2020), and [commit 308d7a7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/308d7a7dc99043c90a9eff6916cad1abe0d473aa), [commit a8fa6a0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a8fa6a08f4ff3ab99f99dd7ae989bd825071def3), [commit b277b73](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b277b737d987b272487f95a6e2afb22edd203553), [commit 8023a5e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8023a5e85bffa969dffab3a509a4c62b2c8906d5) (17 Sep 2020) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b6fb70c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6fb70c985a6fc113e971a6696f328abf8315dce), 02 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`builtin/diff-index`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f5a1d449b9538c2765de9d6683abbb83a7fb4e2): learn `--merge-base`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Denton Liu</sup>

> There is currently no easy way to take the diff between the working tree or index and the merge base between an arbitrary commit and HEAD.
> Even diff's `...` notation doesn't allow this because it only works between commits.
>
> However, the ability to do this would be desirable to a user who would like to see all the changes they've made on a branch plus uncommitted changes without taking into account changes made in the upstream branch.
>
> Teach diff-index and diff (with one commit) the `--merge-base` option which allows a user to use the merge base of a commit and HEAD as the "before" side.
>
> ```
> 'git diff-index' [-m] [--cached] [--merge-base] [<common diff options>] <tree-ish> [<path>...]
> ```

`git diff-index` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0f5a1d449b9538c2765de9d6683abbb83a7fb4e2/Documentation/git-diff-index.txt#L32-L36):

> ### `--merge-base`
>
> Instead of comparing `<tree-ish>` directly, use the merge base
> between `<tree-ish>` and HEAD instead.
> `<tree-ish>` must be a commit.

`git diff` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0f5a1d449b9538c2765de9d6683abbb83a7fb4e2/Documentation/git-diff.txt#L52-L55):

> If `--merge-base` is given, instead of using `<commit>`, use the merge base
> of `<commit>` and `HEAD`.
> `git diff --merge-base A` is equivalent to `git diff $(git merge-base A HEAD)`.

`git diff` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0f5a1d449b9538c2765de9d6683abbb83a7fb4e2/Documentation/git-diff.txt#L52-L55):

> in the `--merge-base` case and in the last two forms that use `..`
> notations, can be any `<tree>`.

And:

> ### [`builtin/diff-tree`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d09c22869a7bd47f1683031937af0ed93b2fa3b): learn --merge-base
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Denton Liu</sup>

> The previous commit introduced `--merge-base` a way to take the diff between the working tree or index and the merge base between an arbitrary commit and HEAD.
>
> It makes sense to extend this option to support the case where two commits are given too and behave in a manner identical to [`git diff A...B`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3d09c22869a7bd47f1683031937af0ed93b2fa3b/Documentation/git-diff.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup>.
>
> Introduce the `--merge-base` flag as an alternative to triple-dot notation.
>
> Thus, we would be able to write the above as [`git diff --merge-base A B`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3d09c22869a7bd47f1683031937af0ed93b2fa3b/Documentation/git-diff.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup>.

`git diff-tree` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3d09c22869a7bd47f1683031937af0ed93b2fa3b/Documentation/git-diff-tree.txt#L46-L50):

> ### `--merge-base`
>
> Instead of comparing the `<tree-ish>`s directly, use the merge
> base between the two `<tree-ish>`s as the "before" side.
> There must be two `<tree-ish>`s given and they must both be commits.

`git diff` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3d09c22869a7bd47f1683031937af0ed93b2fa3b/Documentation/git-diff.txt#L69-L72):

> If `--merge-base` is given, use the merge base of the two commits for the
> "before" side.
> `git diff --merge-base A B` is equivalent to `git diff $(git merge-base A B) B`.

---

With Git 2.33 (Q3 2021), "[`git diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6ca224f1560ec43973e0f1c76bc8ef487a6e107b/Documentation/git-diff.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup> `--merge-base` documentation has been updated.

See [commit eb44863](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb448631fb541239d91709d812b92bf2b57bc733) (10 Jul 2021) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6ca224f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6ca224f1560ec43973e0f1c76bc8ef487a6e107b), 28 Jul 2021)</sup>

> ### [`git-diff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb448631fb541239d91709d812b92bf2b57bc733): fix missing --merge-base docs
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Denton Liu</sup>

> When [`git diff --merge-base`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/eb448631fb541239d91709d812b92bf2b57bc733/Documentation/git-diff.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup> was introduced at around Git 2.30, the documentation included a few errors.
>
> In the example given for `git diff` `--cached` --merge-base, the `--cached` flag was omitted for the `--merge-base` example.
> Add the missing flag.
>
> In the `git diff` `<commit>` case, we failed to mention that `--merge-base` is an available option.
> Give the usage of `--merge-base` as an option there.
>
> Finally, there are two errors in the usage of `git diff`.
> Firstly, we do not mention `--merge-base` in the `git diff` `--cached` case.
> Mention it so that it's consistent with the documentation.
> Secondly, we put the `[--merge-base]` in between `<commit>` and `[<commit>...]`.
> Move the `[--merge-base]` so that it's beside `[<options>]` which is a more logical grouping.

`git diff` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/eb448631fb541239d91709d812b92bf2b57bc733/Documentation/git-diff.txt#L54-L55):

> `git diff --cached --merge-base A` is equivalent to
> `git diff --cached $(git merge-base A HEAD)`.

`git diff` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/eb448631fb541239d91709d812b92bf2b57bc733/Documentation/git-diff.txt#L57):

> ### `'git diff' [<options>] [--merge-base] <commit> [--] [<path>...]`

`git diff` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/eb448631fb541239d91709d812b92bf2b57bc733/Documentation/git-diff.txt#L64-L67):

> If `--merge-base` is given, instead of using `<commit>`, use the merge base
> of `<commit>` and HEAD.
> `git diff --merge-base A` is equivalent to `git diff $(git merge-base A HEAD)`.

Comment: I have Git `2.30.0` version but get this error: `error: invalid option: --merge-base`, any idea why?

Comment: @haridsv What command did you type? I have git version 2.30.0.windows.2, I just tried `git diff --merge-base @~1` and I did not get any error message.  Same for `git diff-index --merge-base @~1`

Comment: Interesting... I thought the commit ref is optional (see: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) so expecting it to diff the `HEAD` against merge base, I just typed `git diff --merge-base`, but when I give a commit ref like in your example, the option got recognized. However, it is not working as I expected. When I run `git diff --merge-base HEAD`, I get no diff, but there is diff that I can see by typing ` git diff $(git merge-base master HEAD)`. Are they not the same?

Comment: @haridsv `git diff` alone would show changes between the working tree and the index. If `--merge-base` is given, instead of using `<commit>`, use the merge base of `<commit>` and `HEAD`. `git diff --merge-base A` is equivalent to `git diff $(git merge-base A HEAD)`. In your case, `git diff --merge-base HEAD` would be equivalent to  `git diff $(git merge-base HEAD HEAD)`, which would result in  `git diff HEAD`, which would compare HEAD and index. If nothing was added, the result would be empty.

Comment: @haridsv I just tried `git diff $(git merge-base master HEAD)` and got nothing. I suppose it depends where your HEAD is (other branch? detached HEAD?)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I guess the right equivalent for ` git diff $(git merge-base master HEAD)` is `git diff --merge-base master HEAD`, I can confirm that both produce the same output in my case.

Comment: Is there a difference between `git diff --merge-base master HEAD` and `git diff master...HEAD` ?

Comment: @haridsv No, it should be the same thing, as mentioned by torek in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41251624/6309

Answer (score 1):

No.  You cannot combine the short-hand notation with a diff against the work-tree.  You must use the longer form.

You can make a Git alias that invokes the shell:

```
alias.basevtree=!git diff $(git merge-base @{u} HEAD)
```

(I'm not sure what your `^` was doing in there) and then run `git basevtree`, but you cannot get it with the three-dot syntax.

Comment: Thanks. Good catch on the `^` too. Wasn't meant to be there.